# $resource:badcfg when calling sharepoint rest service using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, sharepoint

I have an old sample app that calls a rest service and its something like this:
This app does not use angularJS.

```
var listName = "Events";

        // the url to use for the REST call.
        var url = SPAppWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)" +

            // this is the location of the item in the parent web. This is the line
            // you would need to change to add filters, query the site etc
          //  "/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?" +
            "/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=Title,Category,EventDate,Description,EncodedAbsUrl,ID" +
            "&@target='" + SPHostUrl + "'";

        // create  new executor passing it the url created previously
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(SPAppWebUrl);

        // execute the request, this is similar although not the same as a standard AJAX request
        executor.executeAsync(
            {
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {

                    // parse the results into an object that you can use within javascript
                    var results = JSON.parse(data.body);
                    var events = [];
```

The problem is in my new app, I have created an app using angular that reads data from a sharepoint list using rest, however I am struggling with the $resource.query and its options.

I get the error in the title of this post, BADCFG, which means I am not using the right options, I didnt find in the documentation, how to set the  Headers, Accept option in my code.

The code is as follows:

App.Js

```
var SPHostUrl;
var SPAppWebUrl;
var ready = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var param = params[i].split("=");
        switch (param[0]) {
            case "SPAppWebUrl":
                SPAppWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                break;
            case "SPHostUrl":
                SPHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                break;
        }
    }
});

(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("productManagement",
                            ["common.services",
                             "ui.router",
                             "ui.mask",
                             "ui.bootstrap"]);

    app.config(["$stateProvider",
                "$urlRouterProvider",
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/products");

            $stateProvider
                .state("home", {
                    url: "/",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/welcomeView.html"
                })
                // Products
                .state("productList", {
                    url: "/products",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productListView.html",
                    controller: "ProductListCtrl as vm"
                })
                .state("productEdit", {
                    abstract: true,
                    url: "/products/edit/:productId",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productEditView.html",
                    controller: "ProductEditCtrl as vm",
                    resolve: {
                        productResource: "productResource",

                        product: function (productResource, $stateParams) {
                            var productId = $stateParams.productId;
                            return productResource.get({ productId: productId }).$promise;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state("productEdit.info", {
                    url: "/info",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productEditInfoView.html"
                })
                .state("productEdit.price", {
                    url: "/price",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productEditPriceView.html"
                })
                .state("productEdit.tags", {
                    url: "/tags",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productEditTagsView.html"
                })

                .state("productDetail", {
                    url: "/products/:productId",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productDetailView.html",
                    controller: "ProductDetailCtrl as vm",
                    resolve: {
                        productResource: "productResource",

                        product: function (productResource, $stateParams) {
                            var productId = $stateParams.productId;
                            return productResource.get({ productId: productId }).$promise;
                        }
                    }
                })

        }]
    );
}());
```

ProductListrCtrl.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("productManagement")
        .controller("ProductListCtrl",
                    ["productResource",
                    ProductListCtrl]);

    function ProductListCtrl(productResource) {
        var vm = this;

        productResource.query(function (data) {
            vm.products = data;
        });

        vm.showImage = false;

        vm.toggleImage = function () {
            vm.showImage = !vm.showImage;
        }
    }
}());
```

ProductResource.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .factory("productResource",
                ["$resource",
                 productResource]);

    function productResource($resource) {
        var listName = "Products";

        // the url to use for the REST call.
        var url = SPAppWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)" +

        // this is the location of the item in the parent web. This is the line
        // you would need to change to add filters, query the site etc
        //  "/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?" +
            "/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=Id,productName,productCode,releaseDate,description,cost,price,category,tags,imageUrl" +
            "&@target='" + SPHostUrl + "'";

        //return $resource(url);
        //return $resource("/api/products/:productId")

        return $resource(url, {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
            create: { method: 'POST' }
        })
    }

}());
```

Comment: So your question is how to set headers when using `ngResource`?

Comment: well yes, I think thats my error, if you know how please explain me and I will try, I hope thats the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for adding headers:

```
return $resource(url, {}, {
  query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true,
           headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
         },
  create: { method: 'POST' }
});
```

But the error means something different. `query` expects an array and the server probably doesn't return one. Maybe it's because of the missing header, but in your first example there's the comment `parse the results into an object` which could mean that the server doesn't return an array anyway. If that's the case you could add a result transformer.

Comment: looks better, any idea why I see my response like this? http://screencast.com/t/9T5NyaypOi

Comment: the page is so slow! its converting the response (which looks to be html), to an array of 50000 strings or something like that. my browser even gets unresponsive.

Comment: I will post that as a new question, as the badcfg is gone :)

Comment: @EstebanV It looks like the response is an HTML page. Maybe an error page.

Comment: anyway to view in a more friendly manner? how can I join all those strings!

Comment: @EstebanV `var html = ''; for (key in data) { html += data[key]; } console.log(html);`